# Getting values for two labels from single UIPicker

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

[image]Trying to fill two labels using single UIPicker. It has one column, two labels which have two buttons at the end of each label. On clicking which the UIPicker view is shown

```
@IBOutlet weak var userLoc1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userLoc2: UILabel!

let location = ["location1", "Location2", "Location3", 
"Location4", "Location5", "Location6", "Location7"]


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    var countRow:Int = 0

    if pickerView == LocationPickerView{
    countRow = self.location.count
    }
    return countRow
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == LocationPickerView
    {
    let titleLocation = location[row]
        return titleLocation
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == LocationPickerView
    {
        selectedLocation1 = self.location[row]
        self.userLoc1.text = self.location[row]
        self.LocationPickerView.isHidden = true

 //anything that can be done here that can assign different values to 
  //two label  using the same UIPicker

    }
```

Any guide to resolve the matter is greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: How about adding multiple UIPickerview and just calling them accordingly ... Just a Hack!!

Comment: @Smple_V have done that but that just doing it for the sake of it!!

Comment: @matiastofteby have 2 Location labels Location1, Location2 that the user can fill with single UIPicker with 9 Locations. Unable to do this Logic

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra column to your picker view and then add a second array to fill that new column.

It's all the same methods used to initialise the pickerview just with a bit of added logic.

```
let location1 = ["location1", "Location2", "Location3", 
"Location4", "Location5", "Location6", "Location7"]

let location2 = ["location8", "Location9", "Location10", 
"Location11", "Location12", "Location13", "Location14"]

// Set number of columns in your picker view
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
   return 2
}

// Set number of rows of each column to length of arrays
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   switch component {
   case 0:
      return self.location1
   case 1:
      return self.location2
   default: break
   } 
}

// Set content of rows in each column
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
   switch component {
   case 0:
      return self.location1[row]
   case 1:
      return self.location2[row]
   default: break
   } 
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
if pickerView == LocationPickerView
{
   switch component {
   case 0:
      selectedLocation1 = self.location1[row]
      self.userLoc1.text = self.location1[row]
   case 1:
      selectedLocation2 = self.location2[row]   
      self.userLoc2.text = self.location2[row]
   default: break
   } 

   self.LocationPickerView.isHidden = true

}
```

Comment: theres only one column !!

Comment: Why would you restrain yourself to one column? If you want the user to give two inputs in one pickerview the only logical thing would be to provide to columns.

Comment: thanks for the quick response have updated the code as above